# SwiftUI: How to remove text selection between on macOS

Tags: macos, swiftui, textarea

I have two simple text areas with text in them:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View 
{
    @State private var text1 = "Acing cipsusto dictumst ut nisim mincidunt bibendum nostra; tisi niscilit mauris integer. Praesent dolendrem sit tionsequi blandit, iliquamcon quamconsequi aliquam. Doloboreet niat diam facillum torquent, etiam potenti ationullaoret. Euisi ea adignit, modit iliquiscipis, sapien sectem, in quatums vitae sustrud consequipis. Henim faciduisi penatibus, modionsed velisim, consenisim do, lamconullaor sed adiat odionsequip lacinia."
    @State private var text2 = "Ipsustrud wis nostrud ullan. Dolorem nis tue facincil. Enis lor endre consenibh habitant enissim velestionse quatet nullut; niat ver facilisse acidunt sum hendipisim. Fames diamcom conulluptat facidunt landrem."
    
    var body: some View
    {
        VStack
        {
            TextEditor(text: $text1)
            TextEditor(text: $text2)
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that the text selection is retained when clicking between them.

[image]

Text from text1 remains selected albeit greyed out when text2 is selected (or even loses focus). I would have thought this would have been bad UI design to have two selection areas highlighted?

How would I stop this from happening?

Comment: Why is this "bad UI design"? This is standard macOS behaviour. Look no further than Xcode itself. In any case, I doubt you can change that in a clean way.

Comment: Most apps don't do this. I have just checked Mail and Safari to name a few. Anyway I just need to be able to turn it off. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is by design. That's just how two `TextEditor`s behave. It's the default behaviour of the under-the-hood `NSTextView`s. It *should* be possible to select things in multiple text views at the same time. You can see this is exactly how Xcode behaves. Here I am selecting some text in both of the editors, and also some text in the "Quick Help" panel.

[image]

I strongly suggest that you embrace this default behaviour.

If you really want to do something like this, I would suggest doing it in AppKit. This is as simple as overriding `becomeFirstResponder` to call a callback, and setting the selected range of the other text view to empty. A very rough example:

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {
    @IBOutlet var editor1: MyTextView!
    @IBOutlet var editor2: MyTextView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        editor1.onFocusChange = {
            print("Foo")
            self.editor2.setSelectedRange(NSRange(location: 0, length: 0))
        }
        editor2.onFocusChange = {
            self.editor1.setSelectedRange(NSRange(location: 0, length: 0))
        }
    }
}

class MyTextView: NSTextView {
    var onFocusChange: () -> Void = { }
    override func becomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
         onFocusChange()
        return super.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

SwiftUI `TextEditor`s are relatively unconfigurable. You can't change their behaviour much. The only way to clear the selection as far as I know is to force a redraw of the `TextEditor` by changing its identity.

```
@State private var editor1Id = UUID()
@State private var editor2Id = UUID()

@FocusState var focusedEditor: Int?

var body: some View
{
    VStack
    {
        TextEditor(text: $text1)
            .focused($focusedEditor, equals: 0)
            .id(editor1Id)
        TextEditor(text: $text2)
            .focused($focusedEditor, equals: 1)
            .id(editor2Id)
    }
    .onChange(of: focusedEditor) { oldValue, _ in
        if oldValue == 0 { // focus was on the first editor
            editor1Id = UUID() // redraw the first editor
        } else if oldValue == 1 { // focus was on the second editor
            editor2Id = UUID() // redraw the second editor
        }
    }
}
```

Not only does this create a lot of unnecessary `NSTextView`s, redrawing the `NSTextView`s can also have side effects like messing up the scroll position, etc.